# Why Tensorflow's non-standard VGG implementation?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim, vgg-net

Tensorflow  .slim library implements vgg, but replaces the fully connected layers with convolutional ones. The code is at:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/nets/vgg.py

So for example, fc8 layer is implemented as:

```
net = layers.conv2d(
      net,
      num_classes, [1, 1],
      activation_fn=None,
      normalizer_fn=None,
      scope='fc8')
```

which looks like a very different operation, with much fewer weights. 
What is the reason for this?

Comment: 1x1 convolutions are the same as (misnamed) "fully-connected layers" in convolutional networks. See [How are 1x1 convolutions the same as a fully connected layer?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/12830)

Comment: Thanks. The important part  to me,  from the answer in the link was: Note: 1×1 convolutions really are 1×1×number of channels of the input convolutions.